# Free intermediate level documentation

Tags: documentation

Are there any free manuals that are roughly on the level of [Lamport](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201529831), [Mittelbach & Goossens](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201362996), [Kopka & Daly](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321173856), etc.; more in-depth than the [Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lshort-english), but not as daunting as [source2e.pdf](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/doc/source2e.pdf)?

Answer (score 11):

`texdoc texbytopic` may be the level you are looking for.

CTAN: [TeX by Topic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic)

Explanation `texdoc`: [TUG TeXdoc](http://tug.org/texdoc/)

As @lockstep notes this isn't about latex but about tex primitives mostly, however reading that first would go a long way to making the LaTeX sources (source2e) more readable.

Comment: From the OP's examples I infer that the question is about LaTeX documentation.

Comment: Please provide a link to TeX By Topic instead of just writing "texdoc texbytopic", which should be written as `texdoc texbytopic` anyway. Some people reading this might not have any idea what `texdoc` is or do not have direct access to it (atm).

Answer (score 9):

[LaTeX Reference Manual](http://home.gna.org/latexrefman/)

Answer (score 2):

I just remembered that [Math mode](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) is a comprehensive free guide to typesetting mathematics.