# Controlling indentation document-wide

Tags: indentation

Being new to LateX (I have been playing around for less than a week), Im looking for an end-all method to format the indentation for an entire document. This would include:

- subsection indentation,
- paragraph indentation (first line and hanging),
- list indentation,
- list item indentation (first line and hanging),
- table indentation,
- float indentation,
- paragraph indentation which includes a wrapped figure/picture,

So far I just cant seem to get all of these things to work all at the same time.

One method I tried using was encapsulating all my paragraphs in:

```
{\leftskip=0.3in 
  first paragraph
  second paragraph
  list
  third paragraph (embedded picture)
}
```

However that left me unable to indent first lines and lists.

Another method I tried was this

```
\newenvironment{zz}               
        {\list{}{\leftmargin=0.3in \rightmargin=0in}%
                \item\relax}
                {\endlist}

begin{zz}
  first paragraph
  second paragraph
  list
  third paragraph (imbedded picture)
end{zz}
```

But now my text flows right over my pictures. (also, if someone could point out why `\list{}` does anything without a `\begin` starting it that would be very handy).

the methods I am fiddling with right now feel very crude. Is there a way to declare a global formatting for all paragraphs based upon its "Level of Depth"?

Lastly, I cannot find a good resource that is just a reference database of commands, their options, the arguments they take, and how to use/what to use them for. For lack of a better description, something similar to how for java programming, you can find almost anything on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx, it is much easier to help if you extend your examples to be complete small documents that show the problem. Basically `zz` is the right thing (it is the definition of the `quote` environment more or less, setting `\leftskip` directly in latex is just wring and will lead to pain:-) It is hard to know what you mean by "level of depth" your examples don't show any nesting, or multiple paragraphs

Comment: as for your question about `\list`, apart from some error checking `\begin{zzzz}` is just `\begingroup\zzzz` so it often is convenient to use `\zzzz` directly if you know what you are doing and know you don't need the grouping in some context that has already supplied a group.

Comment: As for your reference, `texdoc` is your best friend.  `texdoc <package name>` will 'describe' the package you give it; it will pull up the full manual (almost always as a PDF) that explains the package.  For your indentation, I'd use a combination of `geometry`, `titlesec` and `enum????` (there is a package that deals specifically with lists), keeping in mind that you can have 'negative' indentation for the first line.

Comment: >David Carlisle,
I didnt show any nesting in that example because I didnt want it to grow to large. This was what I was referring to
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure#Sectioning_commands

>Sean Allred,
Thanks, but how do I look up things that are not packages? Things that come built into LateX, e.g. \list?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of good references out there.  Take a look at some of the answers given to [this question on best practices](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/577/22413).  In fact, if you're a complete newbie, I would highly recommend starting with [Leslie Lamport's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201529831).  When I was starting LaTeX, I also found the references mentioned in [this question about intermediate documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51884/22413) quite useful.

As for an on-line reference -- apart from this current site -- I've found
[this TeX FAQ website](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?introduction=yes) very useful and informative.